# Finding tables where there is data

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on a system where there are 50/60 tables. Each has the same unique key (call it `MEMBID` for this example)

Is there a query I can run that will show me the names of all tables that have at least one row where the `MEMBID` exists?

Or do I need to cursor through the `USER_TABLES` table and then build a dynamic query to build up an "array"?

Many thanks

Mike

Comment: would this work ?
select * from user_tables , user_constraints c where rownum >0 and c.CONSTRAINT_NAME ='MEMBID'

Comment: @Moudiz this will give a list of all tables for which the constraint exists, but it won't tell you whether the table contains at least one row with a non-null MEMBID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for dynamic SQL - that's pretty straightforward:

```
declare
  l_cnt_membid number;
  l_cnt_overall number;
begin
  for cur in (select table_name from user_tab_cols where column_name = 'MEMBID')
    loop
      execute immediate 'select count(*), count(membid) from ' || cur.table_name 
         into l_cnt_overall, l_cnt_membid;
      dbms_output.put_line(cur.table_name || ', overall: ' || l_cnt_overall ||
         ', membid: ' || l_cnt_membid);
    end loop;
end;
```

EDIT:

If your table statistics are up-to-date, you can obtain this information from user_tab_cols directly:

```
select table_name,
  (case when num_distinct > 0 
   then 'YES' 
   else 'NO' end) has_nonnull_membid 
from user_tab_cols 
where column_name = 'MEMBID'
```